# System suddenly unstable, short & longs freezes, possibly from 21.10 update

Tags: freeze

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10, as well as let my system generally update its software, and I am suddenly experiencing various stability problems.

### Examples of problems

- Last night, when clicking on the firefox tray icon, system became completely unresponsive. After waiting over 2 minutes and attempting to unfreeze it with some key combos, I had to force power-off and start back up.
- Earlier that day, before the update oddly enough, the system froze in similar circumstances and also required a forced power cycle.
- Now, the contents of the screen seem to be completely freezing every few seconds to minute for between a fraction of to a few seconds. I have recorded an example of this happening here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcN0jPw1ij8

- When using the video editing software to trim down that clip just now, the software (Kdenlive) crashed once and I had to restart the process. When I reopened it, it had strange "blue" content clip in the tray that I didn't insert and wasn't in there by default. ...Data corruption? But also hard for me to say whether this is due to the same general problem or just that one piece of software.
- Ctrl + tab key combos seems to be not be working periodically.
- Various rendering glitches in firefox

Example of a weird glitch:
I try to use dot+space to access 1password to fill in a password field. It doesn't work. There is an "e" character in the password field. I cannot delete the e. I can type text after the e, and delete that text, but the "e" doesn't go away. I try to log in, after letting onepassword complete it. I cannot. I open a terminal window. There is an "e" in it.

Problems are persisting after reboots.

I ran memtest overnight and it didn't detect any memory errors.

I wiped the drive and reinstalled Ubuntu fresh. Problems persisting.

I am running the framework laptop. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu 21.10 is not yet well-supported on the framework laptop:
https://community.frame.work/t/ubuntu-21-10-on-the-framework-laptop/7941
That forum post specifically mentions the cursor freezing problem I'm having.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 21.04, and the problems went away. I'll be checking up on the framework forums in the coming weeks/months to see when they have better support.